# Semicolon expected error in method header

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, static-methods

I know that in method headers you aren't supposed to end it with a semicolon; however, all my method headers display the same error: ; expected. This is for the end of the header as well as between two parameters. How would I fix this?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    // This program will calculate the cost of someone's order at a coffee shop with applied possible  discounts and tax

    public class CoffeeShopWithMethods
    {
      public static void main (String [] args)
      {

        double cost = 0;
        double discount = 0; 

        // Scanner allows user to enter values
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username;
        System.out.print("\nEnter your username: ");
        username = user_input.next( );
        System.out.print ("\nWelcome to Casey's Classic Coffee, " + username + "! \n");

        //call methods
        displayMenu();
        displayOutput(cost, discount, Discounted_cost, tax, Total_cost);

        System.out.println("\nThank you " + username + "! Have a nice day!");
    }

    //outputs the menu to the screen
    public static void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println ("\n\tItem\t\tCost\n\t1. Coffee\t$1.50\n\t2. Latte\t$3.50\n\t3. Cappuccino\t$3.25\n\t4. Espresso\t$2.00");
    }

    //prompts the user to enter item number, returns user input
    public static int getItemNumber(int number) //error: ; expected
    {
        int number;
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("\nPlease enter the desired item number: ");
        number = user_input.nextInt();
        return number;
    }

    //prompts user to enter quantity, returns user input
    public static int getQuantity (int quantity) //error: ; expected
    {
        System.out.print ("\nPlease enter the quantity: ");
        quantity = user_input.nextInt(); 
        return quanity; 
    }

    //takes the item number and quantity and returns the subtotal
    public static double computeSubTotal (double cost) //error: ; expected
    {
        int number = getItemNumber(number);
        int quantity = getQuantity(quantity);

        // Used final double in order to make coffee shop items constant
        final double COFFEE = 1.50;
        final double LATTE = 3.50;
        final double CAPPUCCINO = 3.25;
        final double ESPRESSO = 2.00;

        double cost = 0;

        if (number == 1)
            cost = quantity * COFFEE;
        else if (number == 2)
            cost = quantity * LATTE;
        else if (number == 3)
            cost = quantity * CAPPUCCINO;
        else if (number == 4)
            cost = quantity * ESPRESSO;
    }

    //takes the subtotal and returns true if the user earned a discount; otherwise, returns false
    public static boolean discountCheck (double cost) //error: ; expected
    {
        boolean status;

        if (cost >= 10)
            {
            status = true;
            }
        else if (cost < 10)
            {
            status = false;
            }
        return status;
    }

    //takes the subtotal and returns the dollar amount of the discount earned by the user
    public static double computeDiscount (double cost, double discount) //error: ; expected
    {
        if (discountCheck() == true)
        {
            discount = cost * 0.10;

        }
        else if (discountCheck() != true)
        {
            discount = 0;

        }
        return discount;

    }

    //takes the subtotal and the discount amount and returns the price after the discount is applied
    public static double computePriceAfterDiscount (double cost, double discount) //error: ; expected
    {
        double discount = 0; 
        double Discounted_cost = 0;

        Discounted_cost = cost - discount;
        return Discounted_cost; 
    }

    //takes the prices after the discount is applied and tax rate and returns the tax amount
    public static double computeTax(double Discounted_cost) //error: ; expected
    {
        tax = Discounted_cost * 0.07;
        return tax;
    }

    //takes the price after the discount is applied and the tax amount and returns the final total
    public static double computeTotal(double Discounted_cost, double tax) //says ; expected
    {
        Total_cost = Discounted_cost + tax;
        return Total_cost;
    }

    //takes the subtotal, discount amount, price after discount, tax, and final total and displays all the lines of output to the user
    public static void displayOutput(double cost, double discount, double Discounted_cost, double tax, double Total_cost) //says ; expected at the end of method header
    {
        //call methods
        double cost = computeSubTotal(cost);
        double discount = computeDiscount(cost, discount);
        double Discounted_cost = computePriceAfterDiscount(cost, discount);
        double tax = computeTax(Discounted_cost);
        double Total_cost = computeTotal(Discounted_cost, tax);

        System.out.printf ("\nTotal before discount and tax: $%.2f\n ", cost);

        System.out.printf("\nCalculated discount: $%.2f\n", discount);
        System.out.printf("\nTotal after special discount: $%.2f\n", Discounted_cost);

        System.out.printf("\nTax: $%.2f\n", tax); 
        System.out.printf ("\nTotal cost: $%.2f\n", Total_cost);
    }
} //error:reached end of the file while parsing
```

Comment: May be unrelated, but you have a typo at `System.im`.

Comment: I have cut and pasted your code into a file, and I do not get the errors you're seeing.  I get plenty of other errors mostly about names that aren't defined.

Comment: There are so many compilation errors I can't even begin... Please post a code that compiles!

Comment: @alfasin He's having trouble figuring out why the code doesn't compile.  If he posted code that compiled, he wouldn't have a question!!

Comment: Most of the errors are because he's trying to re-define existing variables.

Comment: You have numerous bugs in your code, for instance in the `computeTotal` method, `Total_cost` has not been declared prior to its assignment

Comment: I get lots of errors about redefining variables and missing symbols.  But I think that if there were a serious syntax error such as a missing semicolon, the syntax errors would still show up.  I think they take precedence.

Comment: I have been working on this too since I posted this, and just made some edits. I realized I had a semicolon on one of the method headers and that took away all of the errors for the semi colon. Sorry I did't realize the edit didn't show it was edited!

Comment: I also had some variables that I already declared and fixed those, as well as not initializing others

Answer (score 0):

1)You are using the variables with out declaring:
for eg: compare this snippet with your code snippet.

```
public static double computeTotal(double Discounted_cost, double tax)
    {
        double Total_cost = Discounted_cost + tax;
        return Total_cost;
    }
```

2)You are invoking undefined methods.
for eg:
you are calling discountCheck() but you have defined like this.
and you have not initialized local variables before using

```
public static boolean discountCheck (double cost){
        boolean status;

        if (cost >= 10)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else if (cost < 10)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

in the above method status should be initialized.

3) You are declaring duplicate variables that are already available to the methods via parameters.
see the code defined by you here:

```
public static void displayOutput(double cost, double discount, double Discounted_cost, double tax, double Total_cost)
    {
        //call methods
        double cost = computeSubTotal(cost);
        double discount = computeDiscount(cost, discount);
        double Discounted_cost = computePriceAfterDiscount(cost, discount);
        double tax = computeTax(Discounted_cost);
        double Total_cost = computeTotal(Discounted_cost, tax);

        System.out.printf ("\nTotal before discount and tax: $%.2f\n ", cost);

        System.out.printf("\nCalculated discount: $%.2f\n", discount);
        System.out.printf("\nTotal after special discount: $%.2f\n", Discounted_cost);

        System.out.printf("\nTax: $%.2f\n", tax); 
        System.out.printf ("\nTotal cost: $%.2f\n", Total_cost);
    }
```

Comment: You have typed system.in as system.im in  your code

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had realized that too once I got past all the semicolon errors

Comment: @mrkrebs you are unneccessarly writing else if clauses in your code

Answer (score 0):

I would start by extracting your `MenuItem`(s) into an `enum` like,

```
static enum MenuItem {
    COFFEE("Coffee", 1.5), LATTE("Latte", 3.5), CAPPUCINO("Cappuccino",
            3.25), ESPRESSO("Espresso", 2);
    MenuItem(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    double cost;
    String name;

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s $%.2f", name, cost);
    }
}
```

Then your compiler errors were mainly due to declaring duplicate local variable names. I was able to fix the compiler errors and produce something that looks like what you want with,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
    String username = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Welcome to Casey's Classic Coffee, %s!%n", username);
    displayMenu();
    displayOutput(scan);
    System.out.printf("Thank you %s! Have a nice day!", username);
}

// outputs the menu to the screen
public static void displayMenu() {
    MenuItem[] items = MenuItem.values();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d %s%n", i + 1, items[i]);
    }
}

public static int getItemNumber(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the desired item number: ");
    return scan.nextInt();
}

public static int getQuantity(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity: ");
    return scan.nextInt();
}

public static double computeSubTotal(Scanner scan) {
    int number = getItemNumber(scan);
    int quantity = getQuantity(scan);

    return quantity * MenuItem.values()[number - 1].cost;
}

public static boolean discountCheck(double cost) {
    return (cost >= 10);
}

public static double computeDiscount(double cost) {
    if (discountCheck(cost)) {
        return cost * 0.10;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static double computePriceAfterDiscount(double cost, double discount) {
    return cost - discount;
}

public static double computeTax(double Discounted_cost) {
    return Discounted_cost * 0.07;
}

public static double computeTotal(double Discounted_cost, double tax) {
    return Discounted_cost + tax;
}

public static void displayOutput(Scanner scan) {
    double cost = computeSubTotal(scan);
    double discount = computeDiscount(cost);
    double Discounted_cost = computePriceAfterDiscount(cost, discount);
    double tax = computeTax(Discounted_cost);
    double Total_cost = computeTotal(Discounted_cost, tax);

    System.out.printf("Total before discount and tax: $%.2f%n", cost);

    System.out.printf("Calculated discount: $%.2f%n", discount);
    System.out.printf("Total after special discount: $%.2f%n",
            Discounted_cost);

    System.out.printf("Tax: $%.2f%n", tax);
    System.out.printf("Total cost: $%.2f%n", Total_cost);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your entire code corrected and working: http://ideone.com/ta0R21 
I really recommend redesigning this. I suggest making use of global variable in some instances.
like the `Scanner` object. Instead of initializing a new `Scanner` each method call, use a global
one to handle the entire job